# How to get value from input with dynamically changed value by jquery UI slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-slider

I've input text with a dynamically changed value by jquery UI slider. How to get value from  `$("#scope_input")` by jquery? `.change` event working only from manual keypress on keyboard, on sliding doesn't getting any value:

```
$("#scope_input").change(function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
});

$("#scope_slider").slider({
    range: "min",
    min: 1,
    max: 100,
    value: 10,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
    $("#scope_input").val(ui.value);
    }
});
```

Comment: where's the code that links to slider??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to trigger the change event manually:

```
$("#scope_input").val(ui.value).change();
```

Answer (score 1):

WHen you update the field within the slide event, trigger the change on the input

```
$("#scope_slider").slider({
    range: "min",
    min: 1,
    max: 100,
    value: 10,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
    $("#scope_input").val(ui.value).change();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
$("#scope_slider").bind("slidechange", function(event, ui) {
    $("#scope_input").val(ui.value);
});
```